# Проблема с почтовиком Thunderbird

Tags: email, freebsd

Приветствую всех! У меня на работе стоит почтовый клиент Mozilla Thunderbird, проблема в том, что у одного нашего сотрудника перестала работать внутренняя почта (у остальных работает). Сначала почтовик перестал заходить на ящик, а при попытке заново зарегистрировать профиль пользователя в программе вылетает сообщение: "Команда PASS не выполнена. Почтовый сервер "имя сервера" ответил: Login failed.". Первое, что пришло в голову: неверный пароль (но т. к. раньше работал, то этот вариант исключён). У нас почтовый сервер (он же и прокси-сервер) использует ОС FreeBSD 6.4. Пробовал использовать для регистрации ящика портабельную версию программы-почтовика, с другого компьютера тоже пробовал регистрировать. Возможно, я что-то накосячил, с файлом netams.conf - я не исключаю это, как вариант, поскольку его правил до того как перестал работать почтовый клиент. Мне посоветовали посмотреть на папке, в которую приходит почта, какие установлены права доступа, но они там у всех одинаковые. Смотрел так:

```
sudo ls -ld /var/mail/exim/имя ящика/
```

После чего, мне выводилось сообщение:

```
drwxrwx--- 5 mailnull mail 512 Aug 27 09:58 /var/mail/exim/имя ящика/
```

Уже и не знаю в какую сторону смотреть для решения проблемы. Жду дельных советов. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Так что, смена пароля проблему не решает?

Comment: Нет, тот пароль, который уже в программе сохранён, верный.

Comment: если тот же клиент настроить на другую учётку, изменив только логин-пароль, что происходит?

Comment: На другую учётку (вход в которую на 100% работает) настраивается нормально.

Comment: А если всё-таки пароль сменить? что ещё особенного в этом ящике может быть?

Comment: надо читать лог, видимо pop3 у вас там. его лог и читайте. попробуйте так-же авторизоваться из-под telnet host 110, примерно такая сессия:telnet mail.host 110USER login_usernamePASS passwordLIST

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, дело в том, что сам по себе Тандербёрд ограничивает длину пароля.

У меня аналогичная история. Я люблю длиииииииииииинные пароли (создаваемые при помощи менеджера паролей). Когда я их полюбил, я заметил, что почту Тандербёрд принимать принимает, а отправить не может, бесконечно требует ввести пароль.

Причём через веб-интерфэйс нормально захожу.

На одном почтовом сервисе - куда я написал в саппорт - меня заверили, что ограничения на МАКСИМАЛЬНОЕ количество символов в пароле они не ставят. И что, скорее всего, проблема в Тандербёрде.

Похоже, таким образом, что сам Тандербёрд ограничивает длину пароля, срезает его часть.

Linux Mint 17, 64 bit. Thunderbird 31.5.0. Отключение аддонов никак не влияет.

Вопрос: **какова максимальная длина пароля в Тандербёрде?**